# Not able to connect with googleApiClient

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I am trying to do g plus signup for my application . Plus api is turned on , sha is generated and deep linking is enabled on the developer website .
However when i try to connect I am not able to .Logging mGoogleApiCLient.isConnected() always returns false
Here is the code I have used :

```
public class GoogleSignUpActivity extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 2;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Log.i("conn", mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() + "");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}




@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN
            || requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()
                && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // This time, connect should succeed.
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
        // String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
        String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
        Log.i("name", personName);
    }
}

public void onDisconnected() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there is a connection issue it should return an error in onConnectionFailed. Try Logging the result, I imagine it will provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, try if you have not checked yet..
Fill **Email Address** and **Product Name** in "Consent Screen" of [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

Comment: I had the exact same problem, even though I already had an email address and product name! What I did, was to select again the SAME email address, in order to force the "Save" button to be enabled and click it. This fixed my issue.